# Picture puzzle: Leaf to Heart

Tags: visual, dissection

## Background

Once upon a time  there lived a poor man.
He was so poor that he had nothing but a low-quality scissor that could only cut three times.

On Valentines day, he wanted to make a card for his mother.
He, of course, didn't want to send his scissors.
When he was thinking, what he could send, a leaf fell to the ground, which looked like this:
[image: leaf]

Then he had an idea: He wanted to make a Heart out of his leaf!

## Puzzle

Can you help the poor man to make a Heart out of the Leaf with cutting the Leaf 3 times, but without throwing away any of the paper?

Comment: Could you please specify how can we cut?? Otherwise this problem is trivial.

Comment: @LakshaySura There is just one answer as I know with just 3 cuts.

Comment: Why do we not use one cut to remove the stem, turn it upside down?

Comment: This is not a leaf... it's a spade...

Comment: @WeckarE. Nothing should be wasted.

Comment: Should the cuts be straight?

Comment: @riskymysteries No

Comment: Folding is okay, and no wasting, right?

Comment: @riskymysteries Yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my illustration as to how this could work:

> [image: Heart]

Comment: Nice answer. I looked for this one.

Comment: @MazurkaFahr XD

Comment: @math is this the answer or is there another?

Comment: This is the rigt answer I was looking for

Answer (score 8):

I can do it with one cut

> "he wanted to make a card for his mother" He folds the card temporarily and cuts once at an angle, thus making a V-shaped cut.Then he pokes the stem of the leaf through. Finally he folds the card in two the other way and glues it closed to cover up the stem.

Alternatively

> Fold the leaf in half along its symmetrically balanced axis. Make a single curved cut to remove the stem then unfold the leaf. The problem here is that folding could damage the leaf and the result not look so good.

Comment: It should be exactly 3 cuts. But still +1 ;-)

Comment: @math - This isn't logical though. If he is so poor, surely he would want to save two of his cuts for some other purpose.

Comment: Ok. I never thought that. ;)

Comment: Exactly the same idea I had in my mind.+1 though for being active.

Answer (score 2):

I think I got this
First cut
Cut it straight from the stem into two symmetrical parts.
Second and third cut
Cut the respective stem.
Glue both the parts and your heart is ready.

Comment: Some say Glue is not there with poor man. We can always use our saliva to join the edges although that's pretty nasty.(Especially in these times)

Answer (score 1):

i don't understand we he should not only cut **twice** instead of thrice...

[image]

we see a wonderful (for better demonstration orange dyed) **Heart**

Comment: You can't waste any piece.

Comment: where did you write that in your question?

Comment: oh man - i see that is written in the comments - as well as my solutions but also these restrictions...  sadly the whole comments were collapsed and not directly visible...